# Localisation English appears double

Tags: xcode, localization

I am starting to localise my app, but I run into the problem that i see English setup twice as Development language.
Not sure why this happens and if I should be worried.
[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple targets as part of your Xcode project?  Does each target have its own localizations?

Answer (score 7):

Close your project in Xcode. In another code editor, open projectname.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj and search for knownRegions. You should see something like:

[image]

Delete the `English,`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your file structure. I guess you have more than one 
Base.Iproj folders

You should have one in

FOLDER/APPNAME Base.Iproj/Main.storyboard

(if you have an localizable.strings file used with Base Localization you also have one in 
FOLDER/Base.Iproj/Localizable.strings
)

Anyway I think it dont do any harm.